# Duda Sobre Texto en Slider

Tags: materialize

Estoy comenzando con Materialize y tengo una duda en cuanto a la ubicación de los textos en las imágenes colocadas en un Slider. En si lo que quiero hacer es poder mover el texto hacia arriba, o hacia abajo o hacia la izquierda o derecha para que me quede mejor ubicado sobre la imagen. Tengo 3 imágenes y quiero que el texto este en una ubicación distinta para cada imagen.Estoy trabajando con SASS lo que estaba intentando era añadir un id para cada div que contiene el texto dentro de cada Caption pero no me funciona. Como puedo lograr esto? gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Comment: de acuerdo a tu sugerencia, por que no creas 3 div y dentro colocas los textos correspondiente, con el atributo text-align los organizas en cada div?

Comment: Ya lo puede resolver amigo, gracias por tu respuesta. Es primera vez que trabajo con Framework, la verdad es muy cómodo pero cada vez se me presenta una nueva duda. como hago para darle mi propio estilo a un elemento, puedo crear una hoja de estilo propia (aparte de la que trae el framework) y trabajarla aparte y luego incluirla?